# Radicals in Gaussian

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, radicals

I want to do a PES scan of a radical structure in Gaussian. However, I'm not completely sure how to prepare an input file. I've figured out that charge and multiplicity are 0 and 2. What I don't know is how to indicate where a radical is. Will Gaussian figure it out itself by bonds and electrons count or do I have to indicate it explicitly?

Comment: Do you remember the postulate "The state of a quantum mechanical system is completely specified by its wavefunction"? Gaussian will find the wavefunction of your input system, which includes the location of the radical in that case (when dealing with wavefunctions, the spin density is the property you want to look at).
Of course, in some cases you can (and should) do something "manually". For example, the 1-propyl radical will lack a hydrogen atom on the first carbon, while the 2-propyl radical will lack a hydrogen atom on the second carbon

Comment: You are approximately solving the electronic Schrödinger equation. Using Gaussian means applying molecular orbital approximation. Radicals are not localised in this formalism. You cannot specify "where it is".

Comment: In case it's not clear yet, Gaussian will figure it out itself. You just need to input the charge and multiplicity with your coordinates and other standard fare.

Comment: Question for downvoters: what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Anna I am not one of the down-voters, but I'd like to give some insight into why you might have attracted them. Broad computational questions which focus about a certain software are not popular with everyone. Conceptual questions (independent of the software) have a better stance. Your question also has a little also appears that you have not spent enough time with the program manual. Such questions are often seen as homework questions which lack in presenting enough own thoughts and effort.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン, thanks. However, this is a question on how to prepare a system for an experiment, so I have to be specific. Not giving the name of the software would be like asking a question about spectroscopy and not saying which one. 

And judging the question as a "homework" is just ridiculous. I was asking for advice on my **experiment**. (Saying this to people who closed the question.) 
If asking for advice is not a proper question, then what is this place? And if computational questions shouldn't be asked, why is there such a tag?

Comment: @Anna computational chemistry is much more than using a program. While there are certain things for which it is important to know the program you are using, in many cases another program can do a similar thing as the concepts are exactly the same. This platform and to gather questions and answers of a broadly applicable nature, it is not so much a forum for discussions. Most of our users expect that a question is well researched, and that the effort going into it is shown. Your question is very basic and can be answered following plenty of tutorials on the net and reading the manual.

Comment: Since you have not included your prior research and where exactly you got hung up on, some users will perceive it as a homework type question; and vote that way. While I don't necessarily agree with that verdict, the decision is made by a community. You always have the chance to [edit] your question to include more details and your thought process. However, I believe your question should be answered through the comments now.